# Set language in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Swift 2 contains function:

```
NSBundle.setLanguage("...")
```

But new class "Bundle" doesn't contain method setLanguage in Swift 3.
What is the best way to set language in Swift 3?

Comment: Are you sure about `NSBundle.setLanguage("...")` in Swift 2? I cannot find that, am I overlooking something?

Comment: He seems to be using an `NSBundle` extension

Comment: Then that should be mentioned in the question, including the code, and where it comes from. Otherwise it is unclear to future readers what `setLanguage` does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setLanguage()` seems to have been deprecated in Swift 3 `Bundle` or you're using an `NSBundle` extension. Instead, here's what you can do:

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: lang, ofType: "lproj")

let bundle = Bundle(path: path!)
```

Then you can use that `bundle` to get a localized string. Here's an extension I wrote for just that:

```
extension String {
    func localized(lang:String) -> String? {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: lang, ofType: "lproj") {
            if let bundle = Bundle(path: path) {
                return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: bundle, value: "", comment: "")
            }
        }

        return nil;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
"any string from the strings file".localized("en")    // or "sv" for Swedish or "fi" for Finnish
```

Comment: I would suggest to not use force unwrapping in your swift code (path! and bundle!), a guard or an if would make the job and save you from crashes.

Comment: NSBundle </var/containers/Bundle/Application/9BEF2AFB-C611-4659-B5A5-97E7B8273335/Dicken.app/sv.lproj> (not yet loaded). I have files: Localization.strings (English), Localization.strings (Swedish), Localization.strings (Finnish)

Comment: Updated answer :-)

Comment: Ugh, that seems like a weird method considering that the language setting is usually a global variable.

Comment: You can always store the chosen language's identifier ("en", etc...) in a global or static string and just use `"string".localized(lang)`. But as far as I'm aware, there's no way to automatically localize strings upon their init